# Mathematics and Law School?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I wanted to make sure the following question is relevant to M.S.E. before posting.

I am studying mathematics at my university, but my performance has not been not outstanding. I am doubtful about a career in mathematics, but I do think the reasoning skills gained from studying math have improved my skills in making arguments. So I have thought about Law School, which I wouldn't have expected to be a common path for math majors. But according to an article about [LSAT scoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_School_Admission_Test#Scoring), math majors score at the top.

Who has studied mathematics and had a successful career in law? What mathematics courses are the most relevant?

Comment: It does seem on the edge of being off topic, but I think it's okay.  [tag:career-development] might be a good tag.

Comment: I think it's a fine question, but I think there's a good chance it will be closed.  I suggest you post it and see what happens.

Comment: I can't help but find it amusing that Pre-Law and criminal justice majors do the worst on the LSAT, according to that list.

Comment: The LSAT is a primitive test, I have helped someone with it. Math people with a reasonable command of English have a big edge.

Comment: While perhaps in some vague sense, the logical reasoning skills obtained via mathematics education might translate to the practice of law, I would be cautious about making too strong of an inference in this regard or using that as your motivation/justification in such an endeavor. Albeit purely anecdotally, I have not found this to be the case, necessarily, and I think you will find plenty of counterexamples on this very meta site and that of MO (in the form of stated opinions/arguments), including some truly shocking ones from world-famous names (in their fields). Caveat discipulus.

Comment: ...and (+1) to this post. If you decide to pose the question on the main site, please edit this post to include a link for future readers. Cheers. :-)

Comment: I have not found a huge correlation between basic mathematical skills and hourly rate for my lawyers. More than once I have had a lawyer figure out the pre-tax equivalent of a payment of $x$ as $x+xr+xr^2+ xr^3$ (sometimes more terms, sometimes fewer) rather than just $\frac{x}{1-r}$.