# Why is Mathematics and Law closed? I based it on Mathematics and Law School?

Tags: support, specific-question, re-open

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790266/79539 was thought of as "off-topic", but the idea is based it on and supported by [Mathematics and Law School?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11664/79539). Hence I'm wondering if we can please reopen the question on the main site? Is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: I see that you have asked 13 questions __none__ of which is a concrete mathematical question that can have a precise answer (naturally, 12 of 13 are tagged 'soft-question'; typical subjects are 'For maximum productivity, how many math subjects or subfields should be studied daily', 'How many times should students repeat reviews? Frequency of repetitions?' and so on). While some soft questions are allowed sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

The type of questions you are asking do not really fit the letter of our guidelines, but perhaps your questions would be welcome at one of the exchanges focusing on math education.

Try https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ . I think your contributions would fit in better there (but sorry if it turns out I'm wrong :) )

Comment: In fact, the OP is the same person who [proposed matheducators.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I find this behavior extremely puzzling then.

Comment: For some reason, the OP has not participated in the Mathematics Educators site.